# Get the highest value of the last 7 days with SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to fetch the highest value (from the column named value) for the 7 past days. I have tried with this sql:

```
SELECT MAX(value) as value_of_week 
FROM events 
WHERE event_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -(7 * 86400);
```

But it gives me 86.1 that is older than 7  days from today´s date. Given the rows below, I should get 55.2 with date 2014-05-16 07:07:00.

```
id  value   event_date
1   28.     2014-04-18 08:23:00
2   23.6    2014-04-22 06:43:00
3   86.1    2014-04-29 05:32:00
4   43.3    2014-05-03 08:12:00
5   55.2    2014-05-16 07:07:00
6   25.6    2014-05-19 06:11:00
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are comparing unix time stamps to date.  How about this?

```
SELECT MAX(value) as value_of_week
FROM events
WHERE event_date > date_add(now(), interval -7 day);
```

Answer (score 2):

Im guessing this is MySQL and in that case you could do this:

```
select max(value) as value_of_week from events where event_date between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`SELECT MAX(value) as value_of_week
 FROM events
where event_date>= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND event_date< curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY;`